# Applet not working on Java 7

Tags: java, browser, applet, java-7

In production env, we use an applet provided by a 3rd party vendor for 2FA login. We dont have any source code, have just the jar file. The applet basically encrypts the login info. Now it works well for most of the users, but few have problem with it using Java 7. It shows the message we put in the applet tag, which usually is being shown if browser doesn't support Java. How to fix the issue on our own (without 2FA team support) as we only hold the jar file?

Comment: Did you check on one of the problematic machines whether http://www.java.com/de/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre&try=1 gives a positive result?

Comment: *"3rd party vendor"*  Sounds like something you should take back to them.  Of course, you can try and force the user to install Java 6 using deployment scripts, but that is intrusive, unwelcome & just a work around for a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to fix the issue on our own (without 2FA team support) as we only hold the jar file?

With great difficulty.

Unless you can identify the cause of the problem by a stroke of inspiration, you would need to decompile and reverse engineer the applet to try to figure out what is going wrong.  There is a fair chance that the applet has been obfuscated to make reverse engineering harder, AND that the license you signed with the vendor forbids reverse engineering anyway.

Talk to the 2FA vendor support.